# How to ensure JS code won't run until DOM is fully rendered?

Tags: jquery

I have a page whose final rendering is adjusted by a bit of jQuery-run JavaScript, having the form

```
<script>
(function ($) {
   //
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

This JS makes its adjustments based on the initial sizes and positions of the DOM elements.

This works well most of the time, but occasionally the results come out way off.

I think the reason for this is that the JavaScript is trying to get positions of elements that have not yet been rendered, so the subsequent positioning calculations come out wrong.

How can I ensure that the DOM is fully rendered before this JS gets run?

Comment: Have you included your script inside `document.ready`?

Comment: `$(window).on('load',function(){...});`

Comment: Is the issue caused by image dimensions and/or dynamically loaded AJAX content which is fired off after you perform CSS calculations/adjustments?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: the page does no ajax, but it does include images.

Comment: @kjo have you set image dimensions on all of your images?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus:no, I hadn't in fact.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: No problem, sometimes javascript/jQuery feels like an endless rabbit hole and just when you think you've reached the bottom it gets deeper.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: soooo true!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>You've said you're already waiting until jQuery's `ready` event fires.</s> *(I* thought *I saw a reply from you in the comments saying you were, but I don't see that comment now and the quoted code doesn't.)* You *could* wait until the `window` `load` event fires, but that happens very late in the process.

Instead, I'd suggest continuing to run at `ready` (or earlier, by putting the script tag at the end of the `body` and not using `ready`), but set a timer to fire and recheck the sizes of the things you're depending on, resizing if those change. The initial timer might be set for "zero" milliseconds (which won't really be), then perhaps again at 50, then 100 or 200, then just resize on `window` `resize`.

Something vaguely like this:

```
<!-- ...content... -->
<script src="yourscript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

...where `yourscript.js` is:

```
(function($) {
    var start = +new Date(),
        loaded = false,
        lastSizes = {}, // Sizes of relevant elements
        resizeTimer = 0;

    // Check resize on load, flagging that load is complete.
    // Maybe resize on resize.    
    $(window).load(function() {
        loaded = true;
        checkResize();
    }).resize(maybeResize);

    // Initial trigger    
    initialResizeCheck();

    // Actually do a resize operation
    function resize() {
        // ...your sizing logic, which sets the sizes in `lastSizes`
    }

    // Check the sizes in `lastSizes` vs. current ones, calls
    // `resize` if they're not set up yet or if they've changed.
    // (Wouldn't be uncommon for this to be combined with `resize`).
    function checkResize() {
    }

    // The function we use early on to proactively check until `load` fires    
    function initialResizeCheck() {
        var elapsed = +new Date() - start;

        checkResize();

        if (!loaded) {
            if (elapsed < 10) {
                setTimeout(initialResizeCheck, 0);
            }
            else if (elapsed < 100) {
                setTimeout(initialResizeCheck, 30);
            }
            else if (elapsed < 500) {
                setTimeout(initialResizeCheck, 100);
            }
        }
    }

    // Trigger a resize when the window is resized, but not until it
    // stops being resized.
    function maybeResize() {
        if (resizeTimer) {
            clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
        }
        resizeTimer = setTimeout(checkResize, 10);
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Those intervals are completely off-the-cuff, but you get the idea. Being proactive, and then adjusting if necessary.

Comment: *And* see MonkeyZeus' thoughts on images. :-)